# In deploy gcloud is not encountering the vendor dependencies

Tags: go, gcloud, vendor

I created by the commands `govendor init` and `govendor fetch "github.com/gorilla/mux"` the vendor directory in the project.

[image]

However, when performing deploy in gcloud `gcloud app deploy` the following error occurs, `github.com/gorilla/mux` is not found:

> ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [9] Deployment contains files that cannot be compiled: Compile failed:
>   /work_dir/main.go:5:5: can't find import: "github.com/gorilla/mux"

What is missing to make deploy work? My plan is free in gcloud

**app.yaml**

```
service: api
runtime: go
api_version: go1

handlers:
- url: /sample
  script: _go_app
```

**main.go**

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "github.com/gorilla/mux"
    "net/http"
    "google.golang.org/appengine"
)

type Foo struct {
    Text string `json:"text"`
}

func GetInfo(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(Foo{"hello"})
}

func init(){
    r := mux.NewRouter()
    r.HandleFunc("/sample", GetInfo)
}

func main() {
    appengine.Main()
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use your vendored version of the mux package, then ensure that the SAMPLE-API files are in a [Go workspace](https://golang.org/doc/code.html).

If vendoring is not required, then delete the vendor directory, run `go get github.com/gorilla/mux` and then deploy your app. In this case, your application files do not need to be in a workspace.

In addition to these build related issues, you must register the Gorilla mux with [http.DefaultServeMux](https://godoc.org/net/http#DefaultServeMux).

```
func init(){
    r := mux.NewRouter()
    r.HandleFunc("/sample", GetInfo)
    http.Handle("/", r)
}
```

Comment: Did not work, appears `404 page not found`. I performed the command `go get github.com/gorilla/mux`

Comment: What specifically did you do that resulted in the 404 page not found?

Comment: I ran the `go get github.com/gorilla/mux` command and then the `gcloud app deploy` Then I went in the browser and put the address `http://api.testcaixa-803f4.appspot.com/sample`. `localhost` it works...

Comment: `localhost` it works but needs the line `http.ListenAndServe(":8000", r)`

Comment: See updated answer.  Use `dev_appserver.py` to run the server locally.  It will help you find these issues before deploying.